How can I be in the same subnet of my switch?
I'm new to networking and I have to get in the admin page for my switch to see how it's configured.
It's IP address is in the subnet 192.168.0.x, while mine is in 192.168.1.x.
I've tried to set a static IP with that range and subnet, but after that my pc won't connect to internet.
I've also tried with PuTTY or telnet but I always received messages like "connection refused" or "timed out", how can I solve this?
Thank you!
